# Componente select desabilitado e valor selecionado angular

Tags: angularjs, html5, html-select

Tenho a seguinte situação

Tenho um componente select de município

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Entidade:</label> 
        <select ng-model="distrito.entidade.idEntidade" class="form-control">
            <option value="{{dis.entidade.idEntidade}}" ng-repeat="dis in distritos">{{dis.entidade.nome}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

EU preciso que esse select fique fixo com a opção selecionada e desabilitada. No caso o usuário poderá ver a entidade  mas não altera-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar a diretiva [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

Como ficaria o seu código:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label>Entidade:</label> 
    <select ng-disabled="true" ng-model="distrito.entidade.idEntidade" class="form-control">
        <option value="{{dis.entidade.idEntidade}}" ng-repeat="dis in distritos">{{dis.entidade.nome}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: fiz exatamento como você sugeriu porém não funcionou, devo comentar também que está vindo mais de uma entidade nesse `select`

Comment: O campo continuou habilitado?

Comment: Sim, permaneceu habilitado.

Comment: Realmente, tinha um erro, editei corrigindo, vê se resolve o seu problema.